# JavaFx TextFlow does not resize on GridPane on change of value

Tags: javafx

I have a TextFlow in a GridPane, when I change its value to a wider one it does not increase its width accordingly on display but truncates. I am a newbie at Java and I've probably missed something simple.

Initial value is built as follows;

```
    TextFlow mhText = new TextFlow();
    // Loop to build TextFlow
    for(Card c : myGame.me.playerHands.get(0).handCards) {
        Text text = new Text(c.cardText(false) + " ");
        if(c.redSuit()) {text.setFill(Color.RED);}
        mhText.getChildren().add(text);           
    }
    playerGrid.add(mhText, 1, pgRow)
```

Then later it is rebuilt...

```
        mhText.getChildren().clear();
        for(Card c : myHand.handCards) {
            Text text = new Text(c.cardText(false) + " ");
            if(c.redSuit()) {text.setFill(Color.RED);}
            mhText.getChildren().add(text);           
        }
```

[Result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpFoh.png)

You can just see from the screenshot that only a dot from the additional 3rd 'card' is showing, I think due to truncation. I've tried using setPrefWidth and setMinWidth without success.

I can solve the problem by removing and re-adding the TextFlow on the GridPane,

```
        playerGrid.getChildren().remove(mhText);
        playerGrid.add(mhText, 1, myHandRow);
```

but I would be surprised if this is the right way, any advice is welcome.